# Как сделать выборку из mysql и запускать php файл в shell / perl?

Tags: php, mysql, perl, shell

Здравствуйте. Нужен shell / perl скрипт, который будет делать select из mysql и запускать php файл с передачей ему полученных данных от mysql (одно поле). После запуска нужно ждать пока php файл выполнится и вернет ответ. Вывести ответ в консоль. После вывода ответа продолжать выборку. В бд более 8 млн записей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Perl, то:

> делать select из mysql

Начать стоит с изучения возможностей [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI).

> запускать php файл с передачей ему полученных данных от mysql (одно поле). После запуска нужно ждать пока php файл выполнится и вернет ответ

Смотря что ожидается в качестве ответа: код завершения, выхлоп в stdout/stderr и т.д. - [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html), [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) с пайпом, [IPC::Open3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Open3)...

> После вывода ответа продолжать выборку.

Perl Syntax -> [Loop Control](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Loop-Control) и дальше.